# Jolt - add common element to array of maps

Tags: json, jolt

i am finding difficulty to add a common map to an array of maps

I have 2 arrays of maps - as shown in i/p json

Now, a common map has to be added to each location array of maps.

When added at 0 index, it is merging with already existing map at the same level.

How can i add without both being merged.

**input JSON**

```
{
  "geo": [
    {
      "locationCode": "USA",
      "locations": [
        {
          "city": "AMS",
          "zip": "1234",
          "sublocations": [
            "included"
          ]
        },
        {
          "city": "EDF",
          "zip": "4567",
          "sublocations": [
            "included"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "locationCode": "FRN",
      "locations": [
        {
          "city": "CVF",
          "zip": "4321",
          "sublocations": [
            "included"
          ]
        },
        {
          "city": "GHJ",
          "zip": "8901",
          "sublocations": [
            "included"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**expected o/p**

i need to add this map -

```
{
                  "city": "XYZ",
                  "zip": "0000",
                  "sublocations": [
                    "included"
                  ]
                }
```

to all "locations" array

```
{
  "geo": [
    {
      "locationCode": "USA",
      "locations": [
        {
          "city": "XYZ",
          "zip": "0000",
          "sublocations": [
            "included"
          ]
        },
        {
          "city": "AMS",
          "zip": "1234",
          "sublocations": [
            "included"
          ]
        },
        {
          "city": "EDF",
          "zip": "4567",
          "sublocations": [
            "included"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "locationCode": "FRN",
      "locations": [
        {
          "city": "XYZ",
          "zip": "0000",
          "sublocations": [
            "included"
          ]
        },
        {
          "city": "CVF",
          "zip": "4321",
          "sublocations": [
            "included"
          ]
        },
        {
          "city": "GHJ",
          "zip": "8901",
          "sublocations": [
            "included"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Jolt spec created**

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "geo": {
      "*": {
        "locations": {
          "#XYZ": "geo[&2].locations[0].city",
          "#0000": "geo[&2].locations[0].zip",
          "#included": "geo[&2].locations[0].sublocations[]",
          "*": {
            "*": "geo[#4].locations[#2].&"
          }
        },
        "*": "geo[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

**o/p as per jolt**

```
{   "geo" : [ {
    "locationCode" : "USA",
    "locations" : [ {
      "city" : [ "XYZ", "AMS" ],
      "zip" : [ "0000", "1234" ],
      "sublocations" : [ "included", [ "included" ] ]
    }, {
      "city" : "EDF",
      "zip" : "4567",
      "sublocations" : [ "included" ]
    } ]   }, {
    "locationCode" : "FRN",
    "locations" : [ {
      "city" : [ "XYZ", "CVF" ],
      "zip" : [ "0000", "4321" ],
      "sublocations" : [ "included", [ "included" ] ]
    }, {
      "city" : "GHJ",
      "zip" : "8901",
      "sublocations" : [ "included" ]
    } ]   } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Principally you can use a **default** transformation to add some attributes to a JSON value while a **modify** transformation would help where to add an object(*collection of the attributes*) within an array such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.&1.&",
          "locations": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "locLen": "=size(@(1,locations))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "locations": {
            "added-city": "XYZ",
            "added-zip": "0000",
            "added-sublocations": [
                    "included"
                  ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&1].&",
          "locations": {
            "*": "&3[&2].&1",
            "added-*": {
              "@": "&4[&3].&2[@(3,locLen)].&(0,1)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "locLen": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]